# iOS Fonts: How to display Coptic Font in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, fonts, uitextview

I have to display coptic font on one of my apps. I did a research and found that it is not supported on iOS. This is the website I referred to.. http://iosfonts.com/

Is there a way I could show it on UIWebView or UITextView?

Looking forward for some solutions..

Comment: UITextView you can just say something like textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"..."];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing custom font file that can display the coptic font.

1. Add the font file (xxx.ttf) into your project.
2. Add "Fonts provided by application" in info.plist. Add the font file name(xxx.ttf) you needed into that array.
3. Use it as `[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];`
      This fontName is not the filename (eg. xxx.ttf, not xxx for this case), you should open your ttf file and see the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

following code is use when the inserting the after installing the font into the project.

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 240, 40)];
[label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Grinched" size:24]];
[label1 setText:@"Grinched Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 240, 40)];
[label2 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Energon" size:18]];
[label2 setText:@"Energon Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label2];
```

And more detail and tutorial regarding the custom font then [goto Reference link here.](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/25/load-and-access-custom-fonts/)